# Appending a text string to wp_enqueue_script

Tags: php, wordpress

So that I can enter my Google API key by using a text box in the WordPress admin area rather than adding it into the code, I am trying to append the text string "$options['text_string']" to wp_enqueue_script;

```
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-gpstracker-google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=' . $options['text_string'] , array(), self::VERSION  );
```

Unfortunately I am not having any luck. The text string is being stored in the options table as I have checked it with PHP Myadmin.

This version of the script works;

```
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-gpstracker-google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MyGoogleAPIKey', array(), self::VERSION );
```

All help is appreciated.

**Update**

Currently I am trying this which is still not working;

```
public function enqueue_scripts() { 
$gpl_key = get_option('gps_plotter_options');
wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-gpstracker-google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?' . $gpl_key . 'libraries=places', array(), self::VERSION  ); 
}
```

Comment: Does adding a period after the $options work?  `wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug . '-gpstracker-google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=' . $options['text_string'] . , array(), self::VERSION  );`

Comment: Unfortunately that causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You have single quote in your options key so that may be causing the problem, tyr replacing the single quote by double quote as below:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_slug.'-gpstracker-google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key='.$options["text_string"][0] , array(), self::VERSION  );
```

Comment: can you show the values stored in $options variable?? are you sure the $options["text_string"] is string not array? 

Please post the content of $options variable.

Comment: Hi Yamu. After further looking into it I believe that $options["text_string"] actually is an array. If that is the case do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I've edited the above code to get the value from the array.(assuming that the array has the required text as first element of the array). If that didn't work then please post the var_dump($options["text_string"])  value and will change the code accordingly.